# Layout design in iPhone X?

Tags: ios11, xcode9, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I was going through **iPhone X** layout design , and i found very important to enable

**use Safe Area Layout Guides** in storyboard .

[image]

As it will help to make View visible , and won't be hidden its UI .

My question is apart from that , as a developer what should i keep in mind while developing application for **iPhone X** so that its design is accurately followed ?

Like when we launch Camera or Gallery , Cancel and other button shown in the top , how to maintain such sort of things ?

Screenshot :

[image]

Kindly provide your feedback on this .

Comment: If you're looking for advice more specific than "follow the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/)" you'll need a more specific question.

Comment: Also see this video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/801/